# Error 500 using Swiftmailer on my website

Tags: php, email

i'm getting mad!

I use switfmailer to send email on every website i have.

My code is simple :

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('username')
  ->setPassword('password');

  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($sujet)
    ->setFrom(array('contact@lavintagecompany.com' => '[La Vintage Company]'))
    ->setTo(array($emailDest))
    ->setReplyTo(array($emailExp))
    ->setBody($texteHtml, 'text/html')
    ->addPart($texteTxt, 'text/plain')
    ;

  $mailer->send($message);
```

I know that this code is working : its works on my website for some years.

I started to set my website from http to https with letsencrypt/cerbot and it works perfectly.

But, since this time, i'm getting an error 500 when i try to send email on a website i have.
I got the same issue on every website on my private server : the code was working like a charm, the code actually works in local (it sends email) but NOT online.

You can try to send mail there : [my website](http://www.lavintagecompany.com/contact.php)

Additionnaly, in the same time and since this day it's impossible for someone to submit a form with recaptcha.

The issue is the same : the code was working, it actually works on localhost but not online
You can try it there : [second website](https://www.fourchette-et-manivelle.com/contact.htm).
Even if you click the recaptcha, it says that "no".

The code (mail and recaptcha) is the same on every website. I didn't changed it.
So i guess that i have a problem on my webserver.

There is nothing in the /var/logs/apache2/error.log :/

I really hope that someone can help me !

Comment: if nothing is showing in your logs, then ask the sysadmin why it's not being written to it. Use error reporting then and set to catch and display. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: apache error log is likely the wrong place to find the error. You need the PHP error log which can be found by running `phpinfo();` or `php -i | grep error` from the cli.

Comment: Here is my phpinfo()

http://www.lavintagecompany.com/test.php

Can't see where to find the PHP error log